# Is this question about setting up beta testing on topic? If not, where would be a better place?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to see what people think about the question below:

[How does one set up a Private By-Invite Beta Site for Android Apps?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/how-does-one-set-up-a-private-by-invite-beta-site-for-android-apps)

It hasn't had much response here - I wonder if the questioner would have better luck on SO?

But it also raises a question for me about whether beta testing is on topic here. Just having "testing" in the name doesn't necessarily make it on-topic here. What do you think?

Comment: I see a beta stage as a large scale UAT, personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While having the word "testing" in the title doesn't automatically mean a post is appropriate, for me, your Beta Testing post is on-topic.

That said, I wouldn't want to see this turn into a "please Beta Test my little app" beg-a-thon.  Thankfully, your post doesn't do that.  Instead, you correctly focus on asking for process tips and tool suggestions from those who have run a Beta program before.

Comment: Seems like a good definition of  on-topic & off-topic - thanks. Should point out the original question isn't mine.

Answer (score 2):

I think that beta testing is on topic here and we should encourage it. I think that the title is slightly misleading on the question and perhaps putting people of viewing. When you actually read the question it seems more like general beta testing management rather than android specific.

Comment: Good point about the title, I'll suggest a change.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there hasn't been much response here because there aren't a lot of people on SQA who have an answer.  I think it's on-topic though.